# How do I use minifs with arrayformula so it autopopulates whole column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Google sheets user here.

I am using the formula minifs to return the lowest match (out of multiple possible match). Is there a way I can use arrayformula as well to auto-populate an entire column so I don't need to copy the same formula to an entire column?

Sample data below:
[image: Sample Data]

Column D and J are data manually inputted. Column I is the formula(s).
Essentially what I want to do here is:

1. Look at Column D - sees the name "Tom"
2. Sees that "Tom" has 3 scores 100, 90, 70 in Column J
3. Formula slaps "70" back into Column I because that is the lowest score
4. Repeats logic for "John" and "Mary"

Note: The actual data type for column J and I is a date instead of a number. But it is easier to illustrate the problem this way.

So I can do this elegantly with the formula: =minifs(J:J,D:D,D2) and D3,D4,D5,D6...etc.
However, I will have to manually drag the formula to the entire column. This is a problem because my colleagues often insert rows in between (and forget to copy n paste the formula to Column I), is there a way I can auto-populate the entire column like I could with an arrayformula?

Comment: Show your sample data and current formula your are using.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see articles 4 and 6 from [this list ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and edit your question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: HI @Harun24HR, question updated

Comment: You should create a minimal, reproducible example, see :  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data are A2:C, you can get the min or max of each row by this way: (you can also add a condition in query)

```
=query(transpose(query(transpose(A2:C),"select " & "min(Col"&arrayformula(textjoin("),min(Col",,row(A2:C)-1))&")")),"select Col2")
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ia05jywxlvT2amFDG4vQhYOd0lo68FKdOY733MzU-MQ/copy

Comment: Thanks Mike. Just added more details to my question - does your solution still works?

Comment: You should have to put an example at the beginning. In fact, it is not the same problem. In your case, you should do a pivot table. Then you can call to the result by GETPIVOTDATA.